# How to transport any component with chakra ui Portal component to dom node?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

if in my `index.html` file, there is a div tag with `"modal-should-be-appended-here"` id:

```
<div id="modal-should-be-appended-here"></div>
```

By default chakra UI's `Portal` will get appended at the end of `document.body`

```
import { Portal } from "@chakra-ui/react"

<Portal>This text is portaled at the end of document.body!</Portal>
```

How to portal this text to `<div id="modal-should-be-appended-here"></div>` instead of `document.body` ?

**Edit**: I know there is a possibility to use with `ref`, but component should be specifically portalled to `<div id="modal-should-be-appended-here"></div>` that is in `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this its

1. Wrap your div in HTML to react component using `React.forwardRef`, like:
   `ModalShouldBeAppendedHere.tsx`

```js
import React from "react";
    
export const ModalShouldBeAppendedHere = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (<div ref={ref} id="modal-should-be-appended-here"/>));
```

2. in you main component or where you want to use `ModalShouldBeAppendedHere` create ref which you want to share between components

```js
const modalRef = React.createRef();
```

3. use wrapper component like `<ModalShouldBeAppendedHere ref={modalRef} />`
4. Use `Portal` with `containerRef` props

```js
 <Portal containerRef={modalRef}>This text is portaled at the end of document.body!</Portal>
```

More about refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that div should stay in index.html. Sorry I haven't been clear. Making an edit

Comment: @JasonM Regarding to the docs looks like it's not possible to render portal content to dom node in raw HTML.